# Bad performance in Find(filter).ToList using MongoDb

Tags: c#, mongodb, .net-core, mongodb-query

I have a collection in MongoDb with 30 million of document and this type of schema:

```
"_id": "63f5f7c7170f3c411c273fc2",
"IdMetadataDocumento": 60,
"IdCompany": 4788,
"IdDocType": 18,
.
.
.
<more than 30 fields>
.
.
.
"DocumentSubject": <array of object>
"DocumentIndex": <array of object>
"AttachmentsIndex": <array of object>
```

I am using only 3 indexes:

- On _id: auto generate index
- On IdCompany and IdDocType because the application always requires filter on these fields
- On IdMetadataDocumento because this is the field in use to sort the result

I am using MongoDb Driver in C# to generate a dynamic filter (method CreateMongoFilter); filter can be done on all the fields of the document collection.

```
ProjectionDefinition<BsonDocument> projection = Builders<BsonDocument>.Projection.Include(x => x["IdMetadataDocumento"]);
FilterDefinition<BsonDocument> filterMongo = CreateMongoFilter(q.Mongo);
var result = collection.Find(filterMongo).Project<BsonDocument>(projection);            
var idmetadata = rows = result.ToListAsync().Result.Select(x => x["IdMetadataDocumento"].AsInt64);
```

This is an example of a filter generated from the method CreateMongoFilter, using BsonDocument type:

```
filterMongo = filterBuilder.Eq("IdCompany", 1)
                & filterBuilder.Eq("IdDocType", 1)
                & filterBuilder.ElemMatch("DocumentSubject"
                , Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.And(
                Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Exists("Role", true)
                & Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("Role", "Author")
                & Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Exists("Name", true)
                & Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("Name", new BsonRegularExpression(new Regex("(?i)^.*jhon.*$")))));
```

Find() method is very quick using different types of filter on my collection.
I have very bad performance when I use ToListAsync() to parse my documents, without a proportional degradation to the number of documents selected.
I am trying different approaches but I haven't found a solution the speed up the performance, yet.
Should I use a different method\approach? Is it the problem related to MongoDb Driver or to the configurations of indexes on MongoDb?

Comment: `Find` - does nothing in this case other than preparing request, the actual command happens in `ToList` method. You have very bad implementation of it though, you almost never should call `Result` on awaitable object. You should either `await` this object if the wrapper method is async or call a sync version (ToList instead ToListAsync)

Comment: @dododo thank you! you are right, this was just an example, but I also tried 'ToList()' method reporting the same problem.

Comment: What does bad performance means in this case? Elaborate on this idea, what is the number of documents fetched for the given filter and how many seconds does it take?

Comment: @RaduHatos in some of my test, it takes almost 1 minute to get one rows in some cases. But it takes the same time to get 1 million rows, or takes less than 1 second to get 1K rows. There isn't a proportion, as I wrote previously. (Time has been taken after ToList()).

Comment: Mostlikely it's unrelated to .net driver, you should analyze your queries in the shell like: `db.coll.find(..your filter..)` or even with explain to better understand what happens on the server side `db.coll.find(..your filter..).explain()`.

Comment: @dododo thank you. I will try to use the `explain()` to get better knowledge of the server side behavior.